# Best Way to Resolve Circular Module Loading

Tags: raku, circular-dependency

I'm trying to have two different objects that refer to each other and also use type checking on the attributes. When I do this I get `Circular module loading detected trying to precompile`. Googling gets me https://docs.raku.org/language/faq#Can_I_have_circular_dependencies_between_modules? which states:

> Note that Raku has no “1 file = 1 class” limitation, and circular dependencies within a single compilation unit (e.g., file) are possible through stubbing. Therefore another possible solution is to move classes into the same compilation unit.

I'd rather not put both classes into the same unit if I can avoid it. I'm not sure how to accomplish this with stubbing since there is no example. The following is a small example of what I'm trying to do:

#### Yak.rakumod

```
unit class Yak;

use YakStore;

has YakStore $.yak-store is rw;
```

#### YakStore.rakumod

```
unit class YakStore;

use Yak;

has Yak $.yak is rw;
```

#### yak.rakutest

```
use lib '.';

use Test;

use Yak;
use YakStore;

plan 2;

my $yak-store = YakStore.new;

my $yak = Yak.new(:$yak-store);

$yak-store.yak = $yak;

isa-ok $yak-store.yak, Yak;
isa-ok $yak.yak-store, YakStore;
```

Yeah, I know, the test is lame, but I just wanted to illustrate the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to deal with circular dependencies is to turn your circle into a triangle – that is, to make both classes that would depend on each other instead depend (at least in part) on some third Role.

Here's how that might look with the example you provided and a `Shaveable` role (`Yak`s should be `Shaveable`, right?):

#### Shaveable.rakumod

```
unit role Shaveable;
```

#### Yak.rakumod

```
use YakStore;
use Shaveable;

unit class Yak does Shaveable;

has YakStore $.yak-store is rw;
```

#### YakStore.rakumod

```
use Shaveable;
unit class YakStore;

has Shaveable $.yak is rw;
```

With that change, the tests in your example now pass.

Comment: I do not recommend this artificial Role approach. Classes layout will become confusing really fast when more `Shaveable` animals will be added. Finally you will be forced to do individual pleonasm stubs like `role YakRole` for each class.

Comment: @PawelPabianbbkr Do you have an alternative suggestion here?

Comment: @uzluisf No, that is the curse of single pass parsers. Deal with tons of Roles that sometimes split your logic artificially (like this Shaveable example, that has nothing to do with OP intention) or get rid of type validation in chosen class to break circular dependency.